# Does /proc/cpuinfo give an updated CPU frequency value each time you access the file?

Tags: python, cpu

I'm making a GUI that displays CPU frequency vs. time on a plot. Problem is, the CPU frequency that I'm pulling from `/proc/cpuinfo` never updates and stays the same.

I'm running Ubuntu.

I'm assuming the problem is in the way I'm making the function that retrieves the frequency.

Any tips?

```
def getfreq():

    with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as f:

        for line in f.readlines():

            lineSplit = line.split(':')

            if len(lineSplit) == 2:

                lineSplit[0] = lineSplit[0].strip()
                lineSplit[1] = lineSplit[1].strip()

                if lineSplit[0] == "cpu MHz":
                    frequency = float(lineSplit[1])
                    return frequency
```

Comment: Have a look at the source code for [i7z](https://code.google.com/archive/p/i7z/) and see how it gets the instantaneous clock speed for each core.

Comment: See also here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87522/why-do-cpuinfo-cur-freq-and-proc-cpuinfo-report-different-numbers